# Datasets do not regenerate code behind

Tags: .net, dataset

So I was lucky enough to inherit a project where someone decided to use datasets as a model. The problem is that a column has been added to table in the database. Using the dataset desinger I added the column to the table and tryied to run the 'Custom tool' That tool is doing absolutly nothing from what I can tell. So is there a way to make the generated dataset code actually represent the changes that are made at the designer?

Now I know why I have never used a dataset. :)

Comment: It might be the wrong custom tool name? What custom tool name are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Goto datasources tab, right click on your dataset and select 'configure dataset with wizard' from ctx menu. In the wizard, expand tables and select the new column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use merging datasets with "missingschema.addwithkey" property and update the dataset using dataadapters:) Easy...